# Adding Adobe PDF Reader COM-Control to WinForm fails

Tags: pdf, axhost

i try to add a COM-Control. The steps i take:
 1. right click in toolbox
 2. choose COMComponents tab and there "Adobe PDF Reader"
 3. click on "OK" button
 4. Now trying to Drag&Drop the Adobe PDF Reader Control into an UserControl 
--> Fails with error:

`"Failed to create component 'AxHost'. The error message follows: 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80004005): A wrapper assembly is not registrated for this type library.
at
System.Windows.Forms.Desgn.DocumentDesigner.AxToolboxItem.CreateComponentsCore(IDesignerHost host)
at
System.Drawing.Design.ToolboxItem.CreateComponentsCore(IDesignerHost host, IDictionary defaultValues)
at
System.Drawing.Design.ToolboxItem.CreateComponents(IDesignerHost host, IDictionary defaultValues)
at
System.Windows.Forms.Design.OleDragDropHandler.CreateTool(ToolboxItem tool, Control parent, Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 width, Int32 heigth, Boolean hasLocation, Boolean hasSize, ToolboxSnapDragDropEventArgse)'"`

What can i do now?

Thanks for every answere in advance.

Greetings, Joe

Answer (score 0):

Try the following
Open Acrobat Reader | Edit | Preferences | Internet
Check the box Display PDF in browser

you will also have to debug using 32bit settings(x86)

Answer (score 0):

Enable pdf for browser by following these steps in Internet Explorer: https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/display-pdf-in-browser.html

Answer is the same as Ahmads but the method of doing it is different in newer versions.